# Report based on year and month

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a report based on a query that groups data per date.

Now I want to create a form with two combobox YEAR and MONTHS. Then let user select criteria from these combobox and upon clicking on a button, the report would open with only data from the selected criteria.

Can someone help me with the vba code that should be on the click event of the button?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a criteria when you open the report:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "YourReport", , , "[DateField] => DateSerial(" & Me![Year].Value & ", " & Me![Month].Value & ", 1) And [DateField] < DateSerial(" & Me![Year].Value & ", " & Me![Month].Value & " + 1, 1)"
```

Replace Year, Month, etc. with the actual names of your controls.